# Set a color for visited links in Google Slides using the Google API?

Tags: javascript, google-slides-api, google-slides

I saw on the Google API resources that mapping can be set for FOLLOWED_HYPERLINK, which is not currently an option in Google Slides. How can I change the visited links color using the Google Slides API?

https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your code with at least minimal level of effort

Comment: I have trouble with the visited Chrome links colors and installed an extension. There are several. Not an answer to your question. Just an idea.